# Are these two matrices equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be a $n\times n$ definite positive real diagonalizable matrix and $D$ the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $M$ (all positive, then). Let $P$ be a matrix the columns of which form a basis of eigenvectors. Then we have $M=PDP^{-1}$.

As $P$ is not unique, let $Q$ be another matrix the columns of which form an another basis of eigenvectors. Then we have $M=QDQ^{-1}$.

Now suppose I have to deal with two matrices which are: $A=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$ and $B=QD^{1/2}Q^{-1}$...

Can I conclude that $A=B$ ? It's my first intuition, but I couldn't manage to go through any demonstration or any counter-example. Could you provide me some help?

Comment: I think the answer depends on your definition of $D^{1/2}$. Is it just any matrix $X$ such that $X^2 = D$? Or do you choose the roots in a specific way?

Comment: OK, sorry! I forgot to say that $M$ is positive definite, so that eigenvalues are positive. Then $D^{1/2}$ is the diagonal matrix containing the square roots of the eigenvalues...

Comment: Just to make it clear: with square roots you mean *positive* square roots, right?

Comment: I amended the post... To answer your questiuon : yes. If $D$ contains $\lambda$, then $D^{1/2}$ contains $\sqrt{\lambda}$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. If $\lambda$ und $\mu$ are two (positive) eigenvalues, then we have $\lambda =\mu \iff \sqrt\lambda = \sqrt\mu$ (since we take positive roots, right?). This implies that for $X\in {\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ we have the equivalences
$$
\begin{align*}
XDX^{-1} = D &\iff D^{-1}XD = X\\
&\iff (D^{1/2})^{-1} XD^{1/2} = X\\
&\iff XD^{1/2}X^{-1} = D^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
$$
More precisely, if $D$ has the form ${\rm diag}(\lambda_1I_{n_1},\dotsc, \lambda_r I_{n_r})$ (with $I_{n_j}$ the $n_j\times n_j$-identity matrix and $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$ for $i\neq j$) then 
$$
\{X\in {\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R) \mid D^{-1}XD = X\} = {\rm diag}({\rm GL}_{n_1}(\Bbb R),\dotsc, {\rm GL}_{n_r}(\Bbb R)).
$$
(And the same for $D$ replaced by $D^{1/2}$.)

Now take $P,Q \in {\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ with $PDP^{-1} = QDQ^{-1}$. Then $(Q^{-1}P) D (Q^{-1}P)^{-1} = D$, so by the above also $(Q^{-1}P) D^{1/2} (Q^{-1}P)^{-1} = D^{1/2}$. Therefore, $PD^{1/2}P^{-1} = QD^{1/2}Q^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I must be tired... Could you explain more clearly how you go from the first equivalence to the second and then to the third?

Comment: The first and third equivalence is just a rearrangement of matrices. The second one should be clarified in the immediately following part. If you don't understand something, please ask a precise question.

Comment: Claudius, the precise question is: I don't understand why $D^{-1}XD = X \iff (D^{1/2})^{-1} XD^{1/2} = X$

Comment: I already explained this in my answer. I simply don't know what your problem is. And you seem not willing to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: OK, Claudius, if you don't want to explain more clearly why $D^{-1}XD = X \iff (D^{1/2})^{-1} XD^{1/2} = X$, then let's go. It does not give me any useful explanation and you do not want to understand that I do not understand some of your statements.

Comment: Pay attention to the set in brackets the equivalence is not as  important as the proof

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Suppose $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $M$ (so that $1\le k\le n$). Let $f$ be any polynomial such that $f(\lambda_i)=\lambda_i^{1/2}$ (e.g. take $f$ as a [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)). Then $f(D)=D^{1/2}$. It follows that
$$
A=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}=Pf(D)P^{-1}=f(PDP^{-1})=f(M)
$$
and similarly $B=f(M)$ too.

Comment: Thanks. For the moment, I dont know enough about Lagrange interpolation polynoms to understand why $Pf(D)P^{-1}=f(PDP^{-1})$, but I will investigate this; it sounds interesting.

Comment: @Andrew This is not specific to Lagrange interpolation polynomial. The equality $Pf(D)P^{-1}=f(PDP^{-1})$ holds for *any* polynomial $f$.

Comment: Good, thanks. So Lagrange is just for assuming that $f$ is not any polynomial but a polynomial for which $f(\lambda_i)$ has value ${\lambda_i}^{1/2}$...

Comment: @Andrew Yes, its sole purpose is to ensure that $f(D)=D^{1/2}$.